# How can I create a consistent <srs> element in a QGIS project's layer?

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, qgs

From a standalone python script (i.e. **not** running within QGIS) I am manipulating QGIS a project file (`*.qgs`) to have its layers point to different geometry data.

That geometry data can be in different spatial reference systems (SRS), so I'd like to also adapt the `<maplayer>`'s `<srs>` child element, so that QGIS will know it and display it correctly in the layer properties dialog.

Unfortunately, (like many other things in the QGIS project files) this element seems to be unnecessarily redundant **and** QGIS seems to actually depend on redundant information for the display. The entry might look like this:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis projectname="" version="2.18.10">
  <!-- ... -->
  <projectlayers>
    <maplayer <!-- ... --> >
      <!-- ... -->
      <srs>
        <spatialrefsys>
          <proj4>+proj=longlat +ellps=intl +towgs84=72.438,345.918,79.486,1.6045,0.8823,0.5565,1.3746 +no_defs</proj4>
          <srsid>3482</srsid>
          <srid>4629</srid>
          <authid>EPSG:4629</authid>
          <description>Tahaa 54</description>
          <projectionacronym>longlat</projectionacronym>
          <ellipsoidacronym>intl</ellipsoidacronym>
          <geographicflag>true</geographicflag>
        </spatialrefsys>
      </srs>
      <!-- ... -->
    </maplayer>
  </projectlayers>
  <!-- ... -->
</qgis>
```

**Having just the PostGIS/EPSG SRID, how do I get the rest of the information needed to create such an entry consistently?** The SRS can differ but is known (by its SRID) at runtime.

I tried giving only the PostGIS/EPSG SRID by shortening the entry to

```xml
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis projectname="" version="2.18.10">
  <!-- ... -->
  <projectlayers>
    <maplayer <!-- ... --> >
      <!-- ... -->
      <srs>
        <spatialrefsys>
          <srid>4629</srid>
        </spatialrefsys>
      </srs>
      <!-- ... -->
    </maplayer>
  </projectlayers>
  <!-- ... -->
</qgis>
```

but then QGIS will not display it correctly in the layer properties:
[image: screenshot of QGIS layer properties window, tag "General" with CRS name and number missing in the dropdown display]
expected:
[image]

(Also, while the data is being displayed, I'm not sure whether it would be projected correctly with that partial information.)

Where does QGIS take this information from when creating a new layer?

Comment: Context (just FYI—should be irrelevant for the question): In [OSMaxx](http://osmaxx.hsr.ch/), we [create QGIS projects](https://github.com/geometalab/osmaxx/blob/d71e2b497693783768f4ce2d59478a04d1065cda/osmaxx/conversion/converters/converter_gis/gis.py#L115-L122) from [jinja2 templates](https://github.com/geometalab/osmaxx/tree/d71e2b497693783768f4ce2d59478a04d1065cda/osmaxx/conversion/converters/converter_gis/symbology/templates) and would like to [get that right](https://github.com/geometalab/osmaxx/issues/874)(er) ...

Answer (score 4):

Do it like QGIS does it internally.

1. Create a `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem`
2. Initialize with [`createFromId`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#a49175edc5f5baf59e7ee8015cfc44f56)
3. use the objects [`writeXml`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#ac6187f872b2910674d041dc1981b4ef0) method

Comment: I guess I would have to install QGIS Desktop or QGIS Server to be able to use this?

Comment: The qgis python modules need to be installed

Answer (score 2):

QGIS reads CRS data from a SQLite db, on my machine this is in `/usr/share/qgis/resources/srs.db`

A rummage in sqlite3 shows several tables and a view (usual caveat, be careful with this!)

These tables (and view) seem to have most of the information shown in the XML snippet as stored in the `.qgs` file

In sqlite3 , `.schema` shows the tables. One of interest is `tbl_srs`, which has the following definition:

```sql
-- Don't run this SQL code.
-- It's just the table definition and would fail anyway.

CREATE TABLE tbl_srs (
  srs_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  description text NOT NULL,
  projection_acronym text NOT NULL,
  ellipsoid_acronym NOT NULL,
  parameters text NOT NULL,
  srid integer NOT NULL,
  auth_name varchar NOT NULL,
  auth_id varchar NOT NULL,
  is_geo integer NOT NULL
, deprecated boolean, noupdate boolean);
```

You can see the mapping from `srs_id` to `auth_id`

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> select srs_id, description, auth_id from tbl_srs where srs_id=3482;
srs_id      description  auth_id   
----------  -----------  ----------
3482        Tahaa 54     4629      

sqlite> select srs_id, description, auth_id from vw_srs where auth_id=3482;
srs_id      description                     auth_id   
----------  ------------------------------  ----------
1440        NAD83(NSRS2007) / Arizona West  3482
```

If you look at the QGIS CRS dialogs, `auth_id` is what is used. EPSG:3482 is something entirely different (NAD83(NSRS2007) / Arizona West)

You can also query the proj4 string. I'm pretty sure there's a way in `pyqgis` to extract individual parts from a proj4 string/CRS, or to convert it into WKT format. But a lot (if not all) of the fields you see in the project file XML are available from this database.

I believe that everything that QGIS knows about a given coordinate system is gathered from those tables / views.

SQLite support is [a standard Python feature](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) since Python 2.5 so it should be reasonably easy to implement.

Comment: Very interesting and promising. And it [seems that this DB is populated from data included with GDAL](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/8ac1460d0e760b288ca20e88529737c3b5cde137/resources/README). The application where I need this already relies on GDAL, so if I can use that I might be able to avoid adding another runtime dependency (QGIS).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess all that information is available somewhere inside QGIS but another source would be to make a call (or two) to http://epsg.io, in your example you can get the proj4 string by parsing http://epsg.io/4629 to get

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=intl +towgs84=72.438,345.918,79.486,1.6045,0.8823,0.5565,1.3746 +no_defs
```

and if you look at the response from http://epsg.io/4629.wkt

```
GEOGCS["Tahaa 54",
DATUM["Tahaa_54",
    SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388,297,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7022"]],
    TOWGS84[72.438,345.918,79.486,1.6045,0.8823,0.5565,1.3746],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6629"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4629"]]
```

You can probably pick up the rest of the parameters.

Comment: This seems like a rather hacky "solution". It'd be a way to get the name in `<description>Tahaa 54</description>` (though I guess GDAL CLI tools can give me that , too), but for getting the proj4 string, calling `pyproj` seems more appropriate. But how would that get me the `<srsid>3482</srsid>` part? That number doesn't appear anywhere on epsg.io, as far as I can see.

Comment: I've no idea what that number is - may be you need to read the source file and see what the comments say